# want to ask why the data that enter only the upper part only(insert multiple)

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The data does not want to loop. When it is stored that is stored only the topmost data only. I want to change the model in codeigniter not allowed to use the code.

```
public function saveTrans1(){

$product = $this->input->post('product');
$product_id = $this->input->post('product_id'); 
$salutation = $this->input->post('salutation'); 
$fullname = $this->input->post('fullname'); 
$email = $this->input->post('email');   
$company = $this->input->post('company');
$jobtitle = $this->input->post('jobtitle');
$address = $this->input->post('address');
$phonenumber = $this->input->post('phonenumber');
$personal = $this->input->post('personal');
$industry = $this->input->post('industry');

$y = count($salutation);
$nom=0;
$nom++;
for ($i = 0; $i < $y; $i++) {
         $postData['salutation'] = $salutation[$i];
         $postData['fullname'] = $fullname[$i];
         $postData['email'] = $email[$i];
         $postData['company'] = $company[$i]; 
         $postData['jobtitle'] = $jobtitle[$i];
         $postData['address'] = $address[$i];
         $postData['phonenumber'] = $phonenumber[$i];
         $postData['personal'] =    $personal[$i];
         $postData['industry'] =    $industry[$i];  
         $postData['product_name']=$product;
         $postData['product_id']=$product_id;
         $postData['password']=$this->randomKey(6);  
         //print ($i);
         $this->v2->inject_transaction_member($postData);
     }
 }
```

Comment: can you show view how you are setting your form fields?

Comment: use ```insert_batch``` may help you

Comment: still an error too

Comment: Can you `print($y)` and tell us what you get? How do you handle your form, could you put your code?